# Determining if $\frac{(-1)^n2n+1}{n-2}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I know a series $S$ with general term $a_n$ diverges if $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \neq 0$. My series is $\left\{\frac{(-1)^n2n+1}{n-2}\right\}$.

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(-1)^n2n+1}{n-2} \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \left((-1)^n \frac{2n+1}{n-2}\right) \\
&= (-1)^n \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2n+1}{n-2} \\
&= (-1)^n \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{2n}{n}+\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{n}{n}-\frac{2}{n}} \\
&= (-1)^n \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2+\frac{1}{n}}{1-\frac{2}{n}} \\
&= (-1)^n \left(\frac{2+\frac{1}{\infty}}{1-\frac{2}{\infty}}\right) \\
&= (-1)^n \left(\frac{2+0}{1-0}\right) \\
&= (-1)^n \left(\frac{2}{1}\right) \\
&= 2(-1)^n
\end{align}$$

Since the limit can never be zero (either $-2$ or $2$), I wonder if this means the series diverges. Can I can do it this way?

Comment: Your series is not divergent, indeed it is oscillating, in other words it is a nonconvergent series whose sum continually fluctuates.

Comment: The third equality is invalid. You can't take $(-1)^n$ out of the limit because it involves $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Just for your curiosity since you already received good answers.*
$$\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n 2n+1}{n-2} x^{n-2}=-\frac{2 x+(1+x) \big[ \log (1-x)+4  \log (1+x)\big]}{1+x }$$
See what happens when $x \to 1^-$.

Answer (score 0):

The equality $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left((-1)^n \frac{2n+1}{n-2}\right) = (-1)^n \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2n+1}{n-2}$ is incorrect. Pulling out the $(-1)^n$ is not allowed because $n$ is the variable you're taking the limit of. Your general idea is correct though - the sequence does not converge to $0$ so the series cannot converge. In fact, the sequence does not converge to anything. Consider the following two subsequences: $a_{2n} = \frac{4n + 1}{2n - 2}$ and $a_{2n + 1} = - \frac{4n + 3}{2n - 1}$. Using a similar argument to what you posted, specifically, the part where you multiplied by $\frac{1/n}{1/n}$, we observe that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{2n} = 2$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{2n + 1} = -2$. Hence, there are two distinct subsequential limits so $a_n$ diverges, implying that $\sum a_n$ diverges as well.

Answer (score 0):

In case you meant $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n (2n+1)}{n-2}, |a_n| \to 2 \neq 0$, so by alternating serier test the series diverges. In case you wrote correctly, it also diverges, because the term can be written as
$$
\frac{(-1)^n 2n}{n-2} + \frac{1}{n-2}
$$
The first diverges by the argument above, the second series diverges because it is Harmonic  series, compare to logarithm.